# Need to be explained the parameters used in connect() in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm a quite beginner to Redux and I want the parameters in the following code to be explained..

export default connect( null, { addTodo} )(AddTodo);

Comment: Please have a look at the official documentation, https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Comment: @Madhumi Munasinghe i think you should follow documentation first for clearing concept and have a look of example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***export default connect( null, { addTodo} )(AddTodo);***

The first argument here is **mapStateToProps**.

If a **mapStateToProps** function is specified, the new wrapper component will subscribe to Redux store updates. This means that any time the store is updated, **mapStateToProps** will be called. The results of **mapStateToProps** must be a plain object, which will be merged into the wrapped component’s props. If you don't want to subscribe to store updates, pass null or undefined in place of ***mapStateToProps***.

The second is parameter is **mapDispatchToProps**.

Conventionally called **mapDispatchToProps**, this second parameter to connect() may either be an object, a function, or not supplied.

Your component will receive dispatch by default, i.e., when you do not supply a second parameter to connect() or you can simply do ***{dispatch function1,dispatch function2}***

**(AddTodo)** is the component wrapped which is subscribed to Redux store updates.